# Helper methods for creating tuples and tupled functions in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, tuples, apache-commons-lang3

I'm using Java 8 along with the Pair from Apache Commons Lang3.

The first thing I am trying to do is get a stream from a `List<T>` and to take a `Function<T,U>` and ultimately create a `List<Pair<T,U>>`. Currently I am creating a `Function<T,Pair<T,U>>` with the specific types I want and using this to map the stream. What I want is something like:

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, Pair<T, U>> tupledResult(final Function<T, U> generator) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(generator);
    return (T t) -> new ImmutablePair<>(t, generator.apply(t));
}
```

The next problem is that now that I have a `List<Pair<T, U>>` I want to be able to use `foreach` to apply a `BiConsumer<T,U>` (similar to the `tupled` function in Scala). I guess it would look like:

```
public static <T, U> Consumer<Pair<T, U>> tupled(final BiConsumer<T, U> consumer) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
    return (final Pair<T, U> p) -> consumer.accept(p.getLeft(), p.getRight());
}
```

Is there anything in Apache Commons Lang3 that does this or should I roll my own? If the later, is this something that is useful to contribute or is this a bad solution?

**Example**

This is the sort of thing I want to achieve:

```
private void doStuff(final List<Thing> things) {
    final List<Pair<Thing, Other>> otherThings = things.stream()
        .map(tupledResult(ThingHelper::generateOther))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    otherThings.stream().forEach(tupled((final Thing thing, final Other other) -> {
        doSomething(thing, other);
    }));
    otherThings.stream().forEach(tupled((final Thing thing, final Other other) -> {
        doSomethingElse(thing, other);
    }));
}
```

The points here are that `ThingHelper.generateOther` is relatively expensive and I only want to do it once. Also `doSomething` must be applied to everything first and then `doSomethingElse` afterwards.

The pairs never leave the scope of this method nor do I want to overload the methods to take a pair. In this case I really don't care about the lack of semantics of the pair, all that matters is the order. `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` are the ones providing the semantics.

Comment: Something to really consider: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#tuples-for-n--2.

Comment: It's funny that java has a lot of `Bi-` types; but it adamantly refuses to have a `Pair`.

Comment: @bayou.io: these `Bi`- types are stateless functions which is a different category than a `Pair` type, which is a *storage*. It’s addition has been delayed because they want to wait to have true value types, but `Optional` has been added as well, being a value type, without having true value types in the JVM yet. Besides that, there *is* a pair type if you can live with it’s impractical name `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`…

Comment: @Steiny: You should not need this verbose lambda syntax `(final Thing thing, final Other other) -> { doSomething(thing, other); }` a simple `(thing, other) -> doSomething(thing, other)` should work as well. Or a method reference…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such methods are absent in Apache Commons Lang3 as this library is Java 6 compatible, but the methods you want must return objects of `java.util.function` package which appeared only in Java 8.

If your `Thing` objects are not repeating, it's quite natural in your case to use `Map` instead:

```
private void doStuff(final List<Thing> things) {
    final Map<Thing, Other> otherThings = things.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), ThingHelper::generateOther));
    otherThings.forEach((final Thing thing, final Other other) -> {
        doSomething(thing, other);
    });
    otherThings.forEach((final Thing thing, final Other other) -> {
        doSomethingElse(thing, other);
    });
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
private void doStuff(List<Thing> things) {
    Map<Thing, Other> otherThings = things.stream()
        .collect(toMap(x -> x, ThingHelper::generateOther));
    otherThings.forEach(this::doSomething);
    otherThings.forEach(this::doSomethingElse);
}
```

This way you don't need wrappers as [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) already accepts `BiConsumer` and [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) second parameter essentially replaces your `tupledResult`.

Comment: You can remove the `final` modifier to make the code even more concise.

Comment: This is much nicer. I like it. Not sure why I was avoiding using a map as these things are not repeating.

Answer (score 0):

In FunctionalJava (https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava) I would do:

```
    private void doStuff(final List<Thing> things) {
        fj.data.List<P2<Thing, Other>> otherThings = fj.data.List.list(things)
            .map(t -> P.p(t, ThingHelper.generateOther.apply(t)));
        otherThings.forEachDoEffect(p -> doSomething(p._1(), p._2()));
        otherThings.forEachDoEffect(p -> doSomethingElse(p._1(), p._2()));
    }
```

Tuples are supported as products with classes P, P1, P2, etc (https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/).